# Stack empty error when trying to add Microsoft Chart controls to a ASP.NET 4 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

I'm trying to get Microsoft Chart controls working on an ASP.NET project. Microsoft have helpfully replaced the samples file with a new version which doesn't include an asp.net code, so I can't look there for help.

On a blank asp.net 4 forms app, if I add the following (or just drag 'Chart' from the toolbar)

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1"></asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

I get the following error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Stack empty.
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

For those asking, I did try adding data. The following code has the same result

```
<asp:Chart ID="chtNBAChampionships" runat="server"> 
   <Series> 
      <asp:Series Name="Championships" YValueType="Int32" ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainChartArea"> 
         <Points> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Celtics" YValues="17" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Lakers" YValues="15" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Bulls" YValues="6" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Spurs" YValues="4" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="76ers" YValues="3" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Pistons" YValues="3" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Warriors" YValues="3" /> 
         </Points> 
      </asp:Series> 
   </Series> 
   <ChartAreas> 
      <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea"> 
      </asp:ChartArea> 
   </ChartAreas> 
</asp:Chart>
```

Comment: did you add data to the chart?

Comment: @VDesign Yes. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: can you give us a preview of your code where you use Stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to manually add the following to my web.config.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ChartImg" verb="*" path="ChartImg.axd"  type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

For some reason this was not auto-added when dragging in a chart component. When I started a new, blank asp.net app and dragged a chart onto a blank page, this *was* added.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was set the path correctly in the ChartImageHandler appSetting...

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=C:\Temp\ChartFiles\;" />
</appSettings>
```